# Create Fields dynamically using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-4, content-management-system, entity-framework-5

I am developing a CMS and I have a category class like this :

```
public partial class Category
{
   public int CategoryId {get;set;}
   public string CategoryName {get;set;}
   public string CategoryType {get;set;}
}
```

I am using Entity Framework to store & create such database table in my database. Now, how can I add dynamic fields to this model and hence to the database. I am allowing the user to add his desired custom fields to be added.
So, my database schema becomes

> Category(CategoryId, CategoryName, CategoryType, CustomField1, CustomField2);

How can I do this using EF 5?

Answer (score 3):

You can't in the way you expect it. Instead of adding custom fields to `Category` table you need something like `CategoryExtension` table where you will store `CategoryId`, `FieldName` and `FieldValue` (key-value pairs related to specific category record) where `CategoryId` will be FK to `Category` table and for example `CategoryId` and `FieldName` will build composite PK. Your classes will then look like:

```
public partial class Category
{
   public int CategoryId {get;set;}
   public string CategoryName {get;set;}
   public string CategoryType {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<CategoryExtension> Extensions { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryExtension 
{
   public int CategoryId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
}
```